# Google charts php mysql and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

Trying with all my best but I just can't figure this out...
I want a user to search a genename in a database. Then update a google bubble chart with the new genename data. Documentation: [https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart][1]

I already implanted the ajax part. So updating the bubble chart with new data after a search is what has to be done somehow....

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSeriesChart);

    function drawSeriesChart() {
      var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "getData.php",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false
        }).responseText;


      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(jsonData);

      var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('series_chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
      var options = {
        title: 'random title',
        hAxis: {title: 'horizontal axis'},
        vAxis: {title: 'vertical axis'},
        bubble: {textStyle: {fontSize: 11}}
      };


    }
</script>
  </head>
    <body>

        <form action="getData.php" method="post">
          Genename:<input type="text" name="gene" value=""><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
        </form>

        <div id="series_chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php

$search_value=$_POST["gene"];
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','usbw','mydb');
$myArray = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM transcriptome WHERE genename LIKE '%$search_value%'")) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
            $myArray[] = $row;


    } //json encode and return to chart.

    //this is how the data looks like hardcoded without the ajax part "['".$row['genename']."', 2, ".$row['TA11MEAN'].", 'control', ".$row['TA11STD']."],";
//2 is position on x-axis + control is groupname
}

$result->close();
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Many thanks in advance :)

Comment: can you post the result of `$myArray[]` ?

Comment: I forgot to come back to this. I solved it by changing the index.html to index.php and just embedding the html. Then echo'ed the php lines into the chart.